# Visibility of source code after contract verification

Tags: contract-deployment, tokens, testing, ropsten, etherscan

I have seen many verified smart contracts with there source code as visible. E.g. [See Here.](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3f0624d68a16f19428584333c1871cdfba0ba870#code)

Now as i want to test my smart contract on Ropsten Network before going live, is it not possible to deploy and verify my contract without having my source code viewable to other participants on Ropsten Network?

If yes, kindly guide me through it with a link to such a contract which is fully deployed with no shared source code and is running successfully on this network (or live network).

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You choose to verify your source code. No-one can make you do that.

Your end user chooses to interact with your smart contract the source code of which may or may not be visible.

Personally, I would never in a million years interact with a smart contract if I couldn't see the source code. How do I know what you do with the money otherwise?

I advise people all the time to either read the source code themselves, or hire someone to do it. You're on the test network, so it's a lot less bad, but if I were you I would start figuring out a business model that includes your releasing your code.

Comment: So, do you mean that it is not necessary to verify a contract but a choice? Also, what are the advantages of getting my contract verified if it's not a necessity?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean. You do not have to verify your source code. Why would you do it? Because I (for one) won't use your contract if I can't read it. I tell everyone I meet not to interact with a smart contract for which they have not read (or had someone read for them) the source.

Answer (score 1):

I think by default the source code is not visible,
but note that the assembly code will be, as the programm must be executed
by someone else.

Comment: When i deployed my contract on Ropsten Network my source code was not visible. As soon as i verified my contract on Etherscan (Ropsten Network) my source code was automatically visible to everyone. I couldn't see any option for managing visibility of my source code.